# Log4j writing raw text as opposed to a logging event?

Tags: logging, log4j

At my company there exists a logging infrastructure that receives logs in json format over a port in the form:

```
{"Type":"<LogName, i.e. INFO>","Message":"<Message>",etc...}
```

I'm using an application that currently outputs it's logs using log4j into some text files, and I'd like to write the logs to this logging infrastructure as well, so I added a [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender) to write to the specified host and port using a PatternLayout of the form

```
{"Type":"%p", "Message":"%m%n", etc...}
```

However, it seems like Log4j doesn't send the message itself -- it wraps this message in some sort of [LoggingEvent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html), of which my message is a field. Apparently this is meant to be deserialized by the server, but since I'm trying to connect 2 pieces of software I cannot do that. Is there a way to send only the message instead of the entire LoggingEvent to a socket?

Comment: Which log4j version are you using?

Comment: Using version 1.2.16

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, I solved the problem by writing my own custom appender, using [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073104/learn-java/write-custom-appenders-for-log4j.html?page=2) as a general guide to the process.